# No route error for edit helper that uses a token as an :id (From Ruby on rails tutorial third edition)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

A url helper I am using does not work, even if it shows at rake routes. Not sure why, hopefully someone could give me a suggestion or point out errors. Something to do with using a token as an id or configuration?

Clicking on this:

```
<%= link_to "Reset password", edit_password_reset_url(@member.reset_token, email: @member.email) %>
```

Gives this error message (email parameter does pass through):

```
No route matches [GET] "/password_resets/$2a$12$Be6H4xiPjqlBtLxAozB7EujVy.2nZSLFJzL3LYDugvDmnn6aoGJ0G/edit"
```

The :new, :create paths work but not the :edit.
routes.rb (The last line):

```
  Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sessions/new'
  root 'static_pages#home'
  get 'help' => 'static_pages#help'
  get 'about' => 'static_pages#about'
  get 'contact' => 'static_pages#contact'
  get 'signup' => 'members#new'
  get 'login' => 'sessions#new'
  post 'login' => 'sessions#create'
  delete 'logout' => 'sessions#destroy'
  resources :members
  resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
  resources :password_resets, only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
  end
```

[image: Rake routes image]
This is from the Ruby on Rails Tutorial Third Edition by Michael Hartl (chapter 10)

Thank you for your time reading this and all answers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that -

Your `edit_password_reset` route is

```
/password_resets/:id/edit
```

but while calling it you are not passing the id but calling it on the member `token` like this -

```
<%= link_to "Reset password", edit_password_reset_url(@member.reset_token, email: @member.email) %>
```

So for the above call to work your `edit` route should be something like

```
/password_resets/<token>/edit
```

The `new` and `create` paths work because they don't require this token. Try to follow the tutorial properly and you will find where you have gone wrong.